# Library: wetterdienst - KeyError: 'parameter' for different locations

Tags: python

I try to get weather data for two different locations, one works another throws an exception, can anyone explain why this is happening?

Library in use: https://github.com/earthobservations/wetterdienst

> KeyError: 'parameter'

```
from wetterdienst.provider.dwd.observation import DwdObservationRequest, DwdObservationDataset, \
    DwdObservationResolution, DwdObservationPeriod


stations = DwdObservationRequest(
    parameter=[
        DwdObservationDataset.TEMPERATURE_AIR,
        DwdObservationDataset.WIND,
        DwdObservationDataset.PRECIPITATION
    ],
    resolution=DwdObservationResolution.MINUTE_10,
    period=DwdObservationPeriod.NOW
)

# works
nearest_station = stations.filter_by_rank(rank=1, latitude=52.122050, longitude=11.619845)
df = nearest_station.values.all().df

#fails
nearest_station = stations.filter_by_rank(rank=1, latitude=52.384630, longitude=9.733908)
df = nearest_station.values.all().df  # <- fails here
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'parameter'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-1a8b9f92e8bd>", line 21, in <module>
    df = nearest_station.values.all().df  # <- fails here
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\wetterdienst\core\scalar\values.py", line 755, in all
    for result in tqdm(self.query(), total=len(self.sr.station_id), file=tqdm_out):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1180, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\wetterdienst\core\scalar\values.py", line 484, in query
    ~parameter_df.loc[:, Columns.PARAMETER.value].isin(self._date_parameters), :
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 925, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1100, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 838, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1164, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1113, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3761, in xs
    return self[key]
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\my_project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'parameter'
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it seems for some locations it doesn't send some data. You should send this problem to author as [issue](https://github.com/earthobservations/wetterdienst/issues). But maybe first try the newest version from GitHub and check if there is similar issue.

Comment: @furas, thank you very much, added full traceback and wrote an issue!